# Python multiple inheritance: Number of arguments for class construction and __init__() method misaligned and resulting in TypeErrors

Tags: python, python-2.7, ironpython, multiple-inheritance

Working on my IronPython project, I have a class called *Formbox* defined below:

```
class Formbox(TextBox, Widget):  

... variables that I treat as static go here ...

def __init__(self, parent, size, position, placeholder_text, formtype=str):
    TextBox.__init__(self)
    Widget.__init__(self, parent, size, position)
    ... rest of the init ...
```

Where *TextBox* is the .NET System.Windows.Forms.TextBox class.

Whenever I try to instantiate a Formbox, such as this way:

#### [Ex 1]

```
LOAD_TEXTBOX = Formbox(LOAD_AREA, Size(20,20), Point(50,50), "Path to file...")
```

The following happens:

```
TypeError: Formbox() takes exactly 1 argument (5 given)
```

If I take away all of the parameters passed in Ex 1, reducing the arguments to the implied *self*, the following occurs instead:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 5 arguments (1 given)
```

If it helps, the Widget class looks like this:

```
class Widget:

    def __init__(self, parent, size, position):
        """

        :type parent:   System.Windows.Forms.Control
        :type size:     System.Drawing.Size
        :type position: System.Drawing.Point
        """
        self.parent = parent
        self.Size = size
        self.Location = position
```

Of course reducing the classes inherited from to one, either Widget or TextBox, causes the Formbox to instantiate correctly. Ex 1 was working perfectly fine until the point that I added Widget to the superclasses.

My question is why exactly are these errors being thrown at me, and how can it be solved such that the Formbox class inherits from both the Widget and the TextBox classes?

**P.S. I am running under the assumption that this is a pythonic error on my part and not a limitation of IronPython**

**P.P.S Most of the arguments in Ex 1 were shortened and simplified for the sake of concision.**

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this easily but I suspect that you are running into a case of mixing [old-style and new-style classes](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes).  The following snippet works fine for me in python 2.6.5, 2.7.6, and 2.7.14.

```
from __future__ import print_function


class Widget:
    def __init__(self, parent, size, position):
        print('Widget(', self, parent, size, position, ')')


class TextBox(object):  # line: 9
    def __init__(self):
        print('TextBox(', self, ')')


class Formbox(TextBox, Widget):
    def __init__(self, parent, size, position, placeholder_text, formtype=str):
        print('Formbox(', self, parent, size, position, placeholder_text,
              formtype, ')')
        TextBox.__init__(self)
        Widget.__init__(self, parent, size, position)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = Formbox('parent', 'size', 'position', 'placeholder')
```

I suspect that `TextBox` is a sub-class of `object` (as shown on line 9).  This shouldn't cause problems since you are calling initializers directly instead of using `super(Formbox, self).__init__(...)`.  Running this example yields the following output:

```
Formbox( <__main__.Formbox instance at 0x7f34ded37b90> parent size position placeholder <type 'str'> )
TextBox( <__main__.Formbox instance at 0x7f34ded37b90> )
Widget( <__main__.Formbox instance at 0x7f34ded37b90> parent size position )
```

Multiple inheritance in Python is pretty well-behaved.  Give [Raymond Hettinger's article](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) on the subject a read.  It is a concise explanation of how to use multiple-inheritance in Python.

In this case, I suspect that there is something going on in `TextBox` that is altering class creation.